# Clamp the scroll wheel value

Tags: xna, c#, mouse

I'm having something like an inventory bar at the bottom of the screen. However, when the highlight square (indicates what object you are going to place) reaches the end. The value of the scroll wheel will keep going up if you keep on scrolling up. So if scroll up a lot, you'll have to scroll a lot back down to change the highlight square position and vice versa for the first square.
I would have thought that this would prevent this problem:

```
highlightPos.X = MathHelper.Clamp(currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue, 0, 480);
```

As you can see I want to basically clamp the scroll wheel value between 0 and 480 but this doesn't seem to work, this is my first time using the scroll wheel so I'm not too knowledgeable on it's in's & out's.

Comment: or clamp the `currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue` directly, or use relative scroll positions

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: by relative scroll position I mean `highlightPos.X += currentMouseState.ScrollWheelDelta;`

Comment: Store ScrollWheelValue every frame and use that to calculate the delta

Comment: Just to be clear is gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; delta?

Comment: But how would storing ScrollWheelValue every frame clamp it between 0 & 480? Do I just do that then the above code will clamp as I expect?

Comment: This is fundamentally a general programming question and should be on StackOverflow; it's also a borderline "debug my code" for me type of question (without sufficient background).

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation for the `MouseState.ScrollWheelValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.scrollwheelvalue%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) notes, you should not use `MouseState.ScrollWheelValue` directly, as it is an accumulated value and most likely will never have the value you expect to.

You will need to store this value every frame and compare with the value from the previous frame to obtain a "DeltaScrollWheelValue", which only then you can use in your code.

I suggest you work with this delta just as you would with the delta time you receive in your `Update()` functions.

This is an example to obtain this delta:

```
// Declare these outside the Update() function
int deltaScrollWheelValue = 0;
int currentScrollWheelValue = 0;

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    deltaScrollWheelValue = currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue - currentScrollWheelValue;
    currentScrollWheelValue += deltaScrollWheelValue;

    // Here you can use deltaScrollWheelValue for your code
}
```

You can also use the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321372/xna-zoom-using-mouse-scroll-wheel) and its code as a reference.

Comment: Taking away currentScrollWheelValue, makes deltaScrollWheelValue jump straight back to 0. Removing that stops that but then clamping the values doesn't work

Comment: Also just found that even with "- currentScrollWheelValue" the clamp still doesn't work. I'm now confused.

Comment: It doesn't jump straight back to 0. You first calculate the delta, and then update currentScrollWheelValue in order to have an updated value to calculate the delta in the next frame. As I said, you should not use this delta as you were using. It's a delta, not an absolute value. You need to update highlightPos.X according to the delta value, and only then clamp highlightPos.X between 0 and 480.